# SwiftUI animation with repeat count ends without animation

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a rotate effect animation that I want to end at a specific number of repeats. the problem I have is that the animation ends without animation and very suddenly. and also in the wrong orientation.

[image]

```
Image(systemName: "iphone")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                    
                        .font(.custom("Masive", size: 60))
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(0))
                        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: isAnimating ? -90 : 0))
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                        .accessibilityLabel("A phone is repeatedly rotating and back")
```

Here is the `withAnimation` that I used on ZStack wrapped the Image.

```
.onAppear {
                withAnimation(Animation.spring().delay(1).repeatCount(2)) {
                    isAnimating.toggle()
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

To fix sudden animation end, you should increase the argument inside `.repeatCount` to 3.

```swift
withAnimation(Animation.spring().delay(1).repeatCount(3)) {
    isAnimating.toggle()
}
```

### Why does this happen?

This "bug" happens because when the `isAnimating` equals true, your image is rotated to `-90` degrees. But the animation values go like:

*(arrow means animation cycle)*

`0 -> -90 -> 0`

So when the animation is ended, SwiftUI still need this view to be rotated, so it does it without any animation. So, we need to use odd values inside `.repeatCount()`

Comment: I tried `3` but the animation ended at `-90` and not 0 as I expected.

Comment: You will need to add another animation toggling the `isAnimating` once more in a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:)` to make it time out for the last turn to vertical. It seems hacky, but it is the only way to implement it.